# How to go from mktime to datetime object?

Tags: php

I have an mktime that I want to have return a datetime object. The best way I came up with seems way too convoluted:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(0, 0, 0, $data[$j]['month'], $data[$j]['day'],$data[$j]['year'])));
```

any better ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [DateTime constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) can take a UNIX timestamp as parameter, so just use the return value from `mktime` directly in the constructor if you prefix it with `@`:

```
$datetimeobject = new DateTime('@' . mktime(0, 0, 0, $data[$j]['month'], $data[$j]['day'],$data[$j]['year']));
```

Or you can skip the `mktime` step completely since `DateTime` can also parse date strings (but this will be more resource hungry, if you're into micro-optimization):

```
$datetimeobject = new DateTime($data[$j]['year'] .'-'. $data[$j]['month'] .'-'. $data[$j]['day']);
```

Comment: As in [DateTime Compound Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php): 
`$datetimeobject = new DateTime(mktime(...));`
won't work.
You have to specify the '@' operator:
`$datetimeobject = new DateTime("@".mktime(...));`

Comment: You are right, although I usually do test my code before answering. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get rid of mktime and make use of native methods of DateTime class?

```
$midOfDay->setTime(12, 0, 0);
$midOfDay->setDate($data[$j]['year'], $data[$j]['month'], $data[$j]['day']);
```